# Deleting custom post types , custom taxonomies and their data on unistalling

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, uninstallation

I want to delete my CPTs and taxonomies when someone uninstalls the plugin.

Since the plugin is already deactivated the only way that i can do this is by issuing directly SQL statements to the db using $`wpdb`.

Is this correct or there is another WordPress way of doing it?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only safe way to do it. [See this question and answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/119229/4771).